MOV to ACVHD conversion via Spring Boot and FFmpeg leads to file system error
I am experiencing an issue on a personal project that seeks to convert HEIC to JPG files and MOV files to AVCHD format. The HEIC to JPG conversion works, but the MOV to AVCHD does not, which is where my problems lie.
The intent is to do this with Spring Boot and FFmpeg, using a simple interface done in WindowBuilder.
The relevant bits are the pom file:
    <dependencies>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jmagick/jmagick -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jmagick</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmagick</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.9</version>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version> <!-- Or the recommended version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freedesktop.gstreamer/gst1-java-core -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freedesktop.gstreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>gst1-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
            <version>7.1-1.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>ffmpeg-platform</artifactId>
            <version>7.1-1.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/javacpp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


and the main file with the event handling for the application, based on the interface:
package home.multimeida.mmconverter;

imports...

public class MMConverterInterface extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        try {
            System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "absolute/path/to/gstreamer/bin");
            // Gst.init("GStreamer Test");
            System.out.println("GStreamer initialized successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to initialize GStreamer.");
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MMConverterInterface frame = new MMConverterInterface();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MMConverterInterface() {
        
        // convert button
        
        btnConvert.addActionListener(e -> {
            
            try {
                
                if (sourceFileLabel.getText().equals("No file chosen...") || destinationFolderLabel.getText().equals("No folder selected...")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select both an input file and a save location.", "Validation Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }
                 
                File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileLabel.getText());
                File destinationFile;
                 
                if (rdbtnNewRadioButton.isSelected()) {
                    
                    System.out.println("Converting HEIC to JPG...");
                        
                    String outputFileName = sourceFile.getName().replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", ".jpg");
                    
                    // Call your conversion logic here
                    
                    destinationFile = new File(destinationFolderLabel.getText(), outputFileName);
                    
                    convertHeicToJpg(sourceFile, destinationFile);
                    
                } else if (rdbtnNewRadioButton_1.isSelected()) {
                    
                    if (sourceFileLabel.getText().equals("No file chosen...") || destinationFolderLabel.getText().equals("No folder selected...")) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select both an input file and a save location.", "Validation Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                        return;
                    }
                    
                     // Validate source file
                    if (!sourceFile.exists() || !sourceFile.canRead()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Source file does not exist or is not readable.", "File Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    // Validate destination folder
                    String destinationPath = destinationFolderLabel.getText();
                    if (destinationPath == null || destinationPath.isEmpty() || !(new File(destinationPath).isDirectory())) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid destination folder.", "File Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    System.out.println("Converting MOV to AVCHD...");
                    
                    String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());

                    // Extract the file name without the extension
                    String baseName = sourceFile.getName().replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");

                    // Sanitize the base name (replace invalid characters with '_')
                    baseName = baseName.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]", "_");
                    
                    String sanitizedFileName = baseName + "_" + currentDate;
                    sanitizedFileName = sanitizedFileName.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9._-]", "_"); // Allow alphanumeric, '-', '_', and '.'

                    destinationFile = new File(destinationPath, sanitizedFileName);
                    
                    
                    /*
                    // Ensure the destination file is writable
                    if (!destinationFile.canWrite()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Output file is not writable.", "File Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        return;
                    }
                    */
                   

                    convertMovToAvchd(sourceFile, destinationFile);
                    
                } else {
                    
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a conversion type.");
                    
                }
                
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage(), "Conversion Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            
        });
        
        // cancel button:
        
        btnCancel.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("Operation canceled.");
            System.exit(0); // Close the application
        });

    }
    
    public void convertMovToAvchd(File sourceFile, File destinationFile) {
        avutil.av_log_set_level(avutil.AV_LOG_DEBUG);
        
        

        AVFormatContext inputFormatContext = null;
        AVFormatContext outputFormatContext = new AVFormatContext(null);
        AVCodecContext inputCodecContext = null;
        AVCodecContext outputCodecContext = null;

        try {
            // Validate input file
            if (!sourceFile.exists() || !sourceFile.canRead()) {
                System.out.println("Source file does not exist or is not readable: " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
                return;
            }
            
            // Validate output file path using the validateFileCreation method
            if (!validateFileCreation(destinationFile)) {
                return; // Exit if destination file validation fails
            }

            // Validate output file path
            if (destinationFile.getParentFile() == null || !destinationFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
                System.out.println("Output directory does not exist: " + destinationFile.getParentFile());
                return;
            }
            if (!destinationFile.getParentFile().canWrite()) {
                System.out.println("Output directory is not writable: " + destinationFile.getParentFile());
                return;
            }

            // Open input file
            inputFormatContext = avformat.avformat_alloc_context();
            if (avformat.avformat_open_input(inputFormatContext, sourceFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, null) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Failed to open input file: " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
                return;
            }

            // Find stream information
            if (avformat.avformat_find_stream_info(inputFormatContext, (PointerPointer) null) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Failed to retrieve input stream information.");
                return;
            }

            // Find video stream
            int videoStreamIndex = avformat.av_find_best_stream(inputFormatContext, avutil.AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, (AVCodec) null, 0);
            if (videoStreamIndex < 0) {
                System.out.println("Failed to find video stream in input file.");
                return;
            }

            // Initialize input codec context
            inputCodecContext = avcodec.avcodec_alloc_context3(null);
            avcodec.avcodec_parameters_to_context(inputCodecContext, inputFormatContext.streams(videoStreamIndex).codecpar());

            AVCodec decoder = avcodec.avcodec_find_decoder(inputCodecContext.codec_id());
            if (decoder == null || avcodec.avcodec_open2(inputCodecContext, decoder, (PointerPointer) null) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Failed to open video decoder.");
                return;
            }

            // Allocate output format context
            if (avformat.avformat_alloc_output_context2(outputFormatContext, null, "mpegts", destinationFile.getAbsolutePath()) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Failed to allocate output format context.");
                return;
            }

            // Initialize output codec
            AVCodec encoder = avcodec.avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("mpeg2video");
            if (encoder == null) {
                System.out.println("Failed to find MPEG2 video encoder.");
                return;
            }

            outputCodecContext = avcodec.avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
            if (outputCodecContext == null) {
                System.out.println("Failed to allocate output codec context.");
                return;
            }
            
            if ((outputFormatContext.oformat().flags() & avformat.AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) != 0) {
                outputCodecContext.flags(outputCodecContext.flags() | avcodec.AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER);
            }


            //outputCodecContext.codec_id(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO);
            outputCodecContext.codec_id(encoder.id());
            outputCodecContext.codec_type(avutil.AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
            outputCodecContext.width(1920);
            outputCodecContext.height(1080);
            outputCodecContext.pix_fmt(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
            outputCodecContext.time_base(avutil.av_make_q(1, 25));
            outputCodecContext.bit_rate(4000000);
            outputCodecContext.gop_size(12);

            if ((outputFormatContext.oformat().flags() & avformat.AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) != 0) {
                outputCodecContext.flags(outputCodecContext.flags() | avcodec.AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER);
            }

            
            
            if (avcodec.avcodec_open2(outputCodecContext, encoder, (PointerPointer) null) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Failed to open video encoder.");
                return;
            }

            // Create output stream
            AVStream videoStream = avformat.avformat_new_stream(outputFormatContext, encoder);
            if (videoStream == null) {
                System.out.println("Failed to create video stream.");
                return;
            }

            avcodec.avcodec_parameters_from_context(videoStream.codecpar(), outputCodecContext);
            
            System.out.println("Destination file path before trying to open the file is: " + destinationFile);

            if ((outputFormatContext.oformat().flags() & avformat.AVFMT_NOFILE) == 0) {
                // Ensure the output path has the correct extension
                String outputPath = destinationFile.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/") + ".avchd";
                System.out.println("Normalized output path: " + outputPath);

                // Try opening the output file
                int ret = avformat.avio_open(outputFormatContext.pb(), outputPath, avformat.AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    BytePointer errorBuffer = new BytePointer(avutil.AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE);
                    avutil.av_strerror(ret, errorBuffer, errorBuffer.capacity());
                    System.out.println("Failed to open output file: " + errorBuffer.getString());
                    return;
                }
            }


            // Write header
            if (avformat.avformat_write_header(outputFormatContext, (PointerPointer) null) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Failed to write header to output file.");
                return;
            }


            // Packet processing loop
            AVPacket packet = new AVPacket();
            while (avformat.av_read_frame(inputFormatContext, packet) >= 0) {
                if (packet.stream_index() == videoStreamIndex) {
                    if (avcodec.avcodec_send_packet(inputCodecContext, packet) >= 0) {
                        AVFrame frame = avutil.av_frame_alloc();
                        while (avcodec.avcodec_receive_frame(inputCodecContext, frame) >= 0) {
                            if (avcodec.avcodec_send_frame(outputCodecContext, frame) >= 0) {
                                AVPacket encodedPacket = new AVPacket();
                                while (avcodec.avcodec_receive_packet(outputCodecContext, encodedPacket) >= 0) {
                                    encodedPacket.stream_index(videoStream.index());
                                    avformat.av_interleaved_write_frame(outputFormatContext, encodedPacket);
                                    avcodec.av_packet_unref(encodedPacket);
                                }
                            }
                            avutil.av_frame_unref(frame);
                        }
                        avutil.av_frame_free(frame);
                    }
                }
                avcodec.av_packet_unref(packet);
            }

            // Write trailer
            avformat.av_write_trailer(outputFormatContext);
            System.out.println("Conversion completed successfully.");
            
            if (avcodec.avcodec_send_frame(outputCodecContext, null) >= 0) {
                AVPacket encodedPacket = new AVPacket();
                while (avcodec.avcodec_receive_packet(outputCodecContext, encodedPacket) >= 0) {
                    encodedPacket.stream_index(videoStream.index());
                    avformat.av_interleaved_write_frame(outputFormatContext, encodedPacket);
                    avcodec.av_packet_unref(encodedPacket);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Cleanup
            avcodec.avcodec_free_context(inputCodecContext);
            avcodec.avcodec_free_context(outputCodecContext);
            avformat.avformat_close_input(inputFormatContext);

            if (outputFormatContext != null && outputFormatContext.pb() != null) {
                avformat.avio_closep(outputFormatContext.pb());
            }
            avformat.avformat_free_context(outputFormatContext);
        }
    }
    
    private boolean validateFileCreation(File destinationFile) {
        // Check if the parent directory exists and is writable
        File parentDir = destinationFile.getParentFile();
        if (parentDir == null || !parentDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Parent directory does not exist: " + parentDir);
            return false;
        }
        if (!parentDir.canWrite()) {
            System.out.println("Cannot write to parent directory: " + parentDir);
            return false;
        }

        // Check if the file exists and is writable
        if (destinationFile.exists()) {
            if (!destinationFile.canWrite()) {
                System.out.println("Destination file is not writable: " + destinationFile);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // If the file doesn't exist, try to create it to verify writability
            try {
                if (!destinationFile.createNewFile()) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to create destination file: " + destinationFile);
                    return false;
                }
                // Delete the file after successful creation to avoid residual files
                destinationFile.delete();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("File creation failed: " + e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    
}



A few caveats:

I did explore FFmpeg and GStreamer for this project. GStreamer was inconclusive, with available version for it that were too old for use with my current state of STS4.27 and Java 17, even if this version of Java is under long-term support...

I've used AI to tell me about the options and suggest ways to build this thing, since multimedia handling is very far away from my skillset. I don't have a good conceptual grasp of video formats and how they transfrom from one to another.


The issue, as I have identified it, occurs at these lines:
 // Ensure the destination file is writable
                    if (!destinationFile.canWrite()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Output file is not writable.", "File Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        return;
                    }

^^ And this, while temporarily commented out for testing, it meant to compensate for an issue that occurs here in the conversion function:
 if ((outputFormatContext.oformat().flags() & avformat.AVFMT_NOFILE) == 0) {
                // Ensure the output path has the correct extension
                String outputPath = destinationFile.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/") + ".avchd";
                System.out.println("Normalized output path: " + outputPath);

                // Try opening the output file
                int ret = avformat.avio_open(outputFormatContext.pb(), outputPath, avformat.AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    BytePointer errorBuffer = new BytePointer(avutil.AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE);
                    avutil.av_strerror(ret, errorBuffer, errorBuffer.capacity());
                    System.out.println("Failed to open output file: " + errorBuffer.getString());
                    return;
                }
            }

The idea here is that the avio_open() function requires the use of the a valid file path that it can open to be able to write it.
Padadoxically, the file conversion seems to work, but the project crashes with a fatal error in the console:
Selected file: E:\TestConveresions\sample_960x540.mov
Save location: E:\TestConveresions
Converting MOV to AVCHD...
Destination file path before trying to open the file is: E:\TestConveresions\sample_960x540_20241231
Normalized output path: E:/TestConveresions/sample_960x540_20241231.avchd
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffcffb0868b, pid=11020, tid=14436
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.5+11 (21.0.5+11) (build 21.0.5+11-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.5+11 (21.0.5+11-LTS, mixed mode, emulated-client, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007ffcffb0868b
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# E:\STS4 Workspace\MMConverter\hs_err_pid11020.log
[80.882s][warning][os] Loading hsdis library failed
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
[AVFormatContext @ 000002528adcea40] Opening 'E:\TestConveresions\sample_960x540.mov' for reading
[file @ 000002528ae51c40] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002528adcea40] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002528adcea40] ISO: File Type Major Brand: qt  
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002528adcea40] Unknown dref type 0x206c7275 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002528adcea40] Processing st: 0, edit list 0 - media time: 2002, duration: 400410
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002528adcea40] Offset DTS by 2002 to make first pts zero.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002528adcea40] Setting codecpar->delay to 2 for stream st: 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002528adcea40] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 1320742 bytes read:38225 seeks:1 nb_streams:1
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] Decoding VUI
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] Decoding VUI
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] Reinit context to 960x544, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] no picture 
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002528adcea40] All info found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002528adcea40] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 51943 bytes read:90132 seeks:2 frames:1
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] Decoding VUI
[h264 @ 000002528ae62780] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[mpeg2video @ 000002528ae8e700] intra_quant_bias = 96 inter_quant_bias = 0


If I refer to the error log, I get this. It is partial, as I'm not sure SO will take all of it (quite long), but still might have enough to be relevant:
Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz, 8 cores, 31G,  Windows 11 , 64 bit Build 26100 (10.0.26100.2454)


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000252d030b340):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0"        [_thread_in_native, id=14436, stack(0x000000a4e2b00000,0x000000a4e2c00000) (1024K)]

Stack: [0x000000a4e2b00000,0x000000a4e2c00000],  sp=0x000000a4e2bfdf30,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x00007ffcffb0868b

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avformat.avio_open(Lorg/bytedeco/ffmpeg/avformat/AVIOContext;Ljava/lang/String;I)I+0
j  home.multimeida.mmconverter.MMConverterInterface.convertMovToAvchd(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/io/File;)V+1120
j  home.multimeida.mmconverter.MMConverterInterface.lambda$2(Ljavax/swing/JRadioButton;Ljavax/swing/JRadioButton;Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+347
j  home.multimeida.mmconverter.MMConverterInterface$$Lambda+0x000002528c0c7778.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+13
j  javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+84 java.desktop@21.0.5
j  javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+5 java.desktop@21.0.5
j  javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+34 java.desktop@21.0.5
j  javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Z)V+117 java.desktop@21.0.5
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+35 java.desktop@21.0.5
j  java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+64 java.desktop@21.0.5
j  javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+23 java.desktop@21.0.5
J 2581 c1 java.awt.Component.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@21.0.5 (220 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa62719c [0x00000252fa627020+0x000000000000017c]
J 2580 c1 java.awt.Container.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@21.0.5 (22 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa627d9c [0x00000252fa627cc0+0x00000000000000dc]
J 2406 c1 java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@21.0.5 (785 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa670f14 [0x00000252fa670040+0x0000000000000ed4]
J 2325 c1 java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@21.0.5 (129 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa64e93c [0x00000252fa64e8a0+0x000000000000009c]
J 2608 c1 java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/Component;ILjava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V java.desktop@21.0.5 (372 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa61c364 [0x00000252fa61b9e0+0x0000000000000984]
J 2578 c1 java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)Z java.desktop@21.0.5 (268 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa628a54 [0x00000252fa6284c0+0x0000000000000594]
J 2474 c1 java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)Z java.desktop@21.0.5 (73 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa699bbc [0x00000252fa699a60+0x000000000000015c]
J 2325 c1 java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@21.0.5 (129 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa64e914 [0x00000252fa64e8a0+0x0000000000000074]
J 2473 c1 java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@21.0.5 (23 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa699654 [0x00000252fa6994e0+0x0000000000000174]
J 1838 c1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V java.desktop@21.0.5 (139 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa3bec64 [0x00000252fa3beb20+0x0000000000000144]
J 1837 c1 java.awt.EventQueue$4.run()Ljava/lang/Void; java.desktop@21.0.5 (60 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa3c0504 [0x00000252fa3c0460+0x00000000000000a4]
J 1836 c1 java.awt.EventQueue$4.run()Ljava/lang/Object; java.desktop@21.0.5 (5 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa3c0a04 [0x00000252fa3c09c0+0x0000000000000044]
J 1778 c1 java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@21.0.5 (22 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa4601d4 [0x00000252fa45ffa0+0x0000000000000234]
J 1832 c1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@21.0.5 (80 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa44f14c [0x00000252fa44eae0+0x000000000000066c]
J 1846 c1 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V java.desktop@21.0.5 (106 bytes) @ 0x00000252fa3ba544 [0x00000252fa3ba2e0+0x0000000000000264]
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35 java.desktop@21.0.5
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11 java.desktop@21.0.5
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4 java.desktop@21.0.5
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3 java.desktop@21.0.5
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9 java.desktop@21.0.5
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub 0x00000252fa08100d

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), writing address 0x0000000000000000


If anyone has a perspective on this, it'd be appreciated.
The catch 22 in this project is that pre-creating the file is not a good idea, since avio_open has a purpose in-built method for that (I tried). Error checking everything about Java's File class in terms of setting pathways and creating and deleting files is not problematic. Likewise, permissions are all fine (Full Control in source and target folders); I've tested default C drive folders, which have restritions, to a separate volume and removable media, to no effect. Likewise, FFmpeg requires a forward slash, "/" in file paths, whereas Java does the backslash, generally. That's been handled with the replace method in the above conditioning, also to no effect.
The basic contradiction in the project seems to be that the error tries open a file that does not exist, with a valid source and destination file, and if I try to create a placeholder file wiht an acvhd extension at the event handling for the Convert button, it still errors out; meanwhile, FFmpeg allegedly handles the file creation at its core, but requires a valid path to be passed; I've tried with and without a filename, with and without an extension. I'm not able to resovle it.
The excessive error handling conditions are in an effort to isolate the problem, which I think I've done.
There also seems to be a compatibility between mpegts and acvhd, which is why I also had that format specified in the conversion function, without result.
I also have the idea to be able to do this without having to install any libraries locally or having to set path variables, which is an aspect that both GStreamer and FFmpeg have.
Nearest suggestion I've found is this: integrate ffmpeg with spring boot
AI remains hopeless for resolving this issue.
